# Is "Ellos no le compran a ella ningún regalo" a gramatically correct sentence?

Tags: gramática

Basically I'm wondering where the clarification "a ella" should go. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is correct.

In Spanish, subject, verb and complements can be ordered in almost any way.

> Ellos a ella no le compran ningún regalo.
>   Ellos no le compran a ella ningún regalo.
>   Ellos no le compran ningún regalo a ella.

The three are equally correct.

> A ella no le compran ellos ningún regalo.
>   Ningún regalo a ella le compran ellos.
>   A ella ellos ningún regalo le compran.

All correct (although much less common outside of literature).